# How to deal with several hour range in JQuery or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created a list of hour range for user to book a room for each day. This is the hour range that is allowed.

```
START HOUR         FINISH HOUR
     08:00               08:00
     09:00               09:00
     10:00               10:00
     11:00               11:00
     12:00               12:00
```

Form above list user input may be:

```
08:00 - 09:00, 
08:00 - 10:00, 
08:00 - 11:00,
08:00 - 12:00,
09:00 - 10:00,
09:00 - 11:00,
09:00 - 12:00,
10:00 - 11:00,
10:00 - 12:00,
11:00 - 12:00
```

My current script only handle maximum `FINISH HOUR`. So, if there's a book today at 08:00 - 10:00, other user can only book at >= 10:00. But, there's some problem here. If there's a book today from 10:00 - 11:00, then other user forced to book at >= 11:00 while 08:00 - 09:00 or 08:00 - 10:00 or 09:00 - 10:00 is free. How to deal with this?

This is my current script:

```
//CHECK HOURS PER ROOM PER DAY
    var url_check   = "<?php print base_url(); ?>reservasi_rapat/check_hour";

    var val_date    = $('#i_tglbook').val();  //date variable       

    var max_start;
    var max_finish;

    $.ajax({
        url         : url_check,
        type        : 'POST',
        dataType    : 'json',
        data        : { date_book : val_date },
        async       :false,
        success     : function(data){

            max_start    = data.book[0]['MAX_JAM_MULAI']; //max start date from DB
            max_finish   = data.book[0]['MAX_JAM_SELESAI']; //max finish date from DB
        }
    });

    if(max_start != null || max_finish != null){   //book for the first time

        var jam_1          = $('#start').find('option:selected').val(); //selected start date
        var jam_2          = $('#finish').find('option:selected').val(); //selected end date

        var jam_dari       = jam_1.split(/:/);
        var val_dari       = (jam_dari[0] * 3600) + (jam_dari[1] * 60);

        var jam_sampai     = jam_2.split(/:/);
        var val_sampai     = (jam_sampai[0] * 3600) + (jam_sampai[1] * 60);

        var max_dari       = max_jam_mulai.split(/:/);
        var val_dari_max   = (max_dari[0] * 3600) + (max_dari[1] * 60);

        var max_sampai     = max_jam_selesai.split(/:/);
        var val_sampai_max = (max_sampai[0] * 3600) + (max_sampai[1] * 60);

        if(val_dari < val_sampai_max){

            alert("Start date must be >= "+max_finish);     

            $('#start').blur();
            $('#start').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        }                   
    }
```

Comment: Before even trying to fix that: Shouldn't you considder some time for cleaning up a room before passing it on to another user? Anyway, I would go with a different approach. Instead of trying to force a time after the previous user, I would have PHP return the "occupied" times and remove those from a default list with all the possible times. Leaving only the options that are still available.

Comment: @icecub yes that would be nice. But, the hour range may change from time to time. Like adding the minute. So, there will be a very long list of `occupied` table

Comment: You would run into that problem either way. That's why you have a database available to you. It allowes you to set the ranges dynamicly instead of using static values. And the amount of "occupied" data returned doesn't matter. You don't have to show those to users. If for example there are 3 dates like `08:00 - 09:00 / 09:00 - 10:00 / 10:00-11:00`, all you might want to show is `08:00 - 11:00 = unavailable`. Or dont show it at all. Only show what _is_ available

Comment: Remember that the "occupied" data is only needed for your server to display wat _is_ still available. You're talking to a processor capable of calculating billions of operations per second. Even if you returned a thousend occupied timetables on a single day, the server will handle it within a fraction of a second.

Comment: @icecub I'll consider that. But, still need to fix this problem first :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I'm definitely not trying to be an ass here or something! But why would you try to fix a faulty approach in the first place? That's like diving into the ocean without any swimming certificates and actually swimming to the bottom! I mean, it's your code. I won't judge. But if you continue on this path, the issues will only get worse down the road.